# Getting frames from video with tuning frames?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am having having a video and i used following code to get the frames from the video. The video was of 24 sec and i got 742 images. I want to tune this part in my code to get more number of image from a video.

and also the frames i get are tilted 90* anticlockwise. Please help me with it.

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('20180530_115209.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
while success:
    cv2.imwrite("sushant_2/image/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file      
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    print('Read a new frame: ', count)
    count += 1
```

Comment: try cv2.VideoWriter(), if you want to change fps

Comment: 742 frames / 24 s = 30 fps. Did your video have a different framerate? What is the expected result?

Comment: You can only speed up the process of getting the frames (increasing the fps of the video)

Comment: What is the encoding of your video format? Also, make sure that you have latest version of FFmpeg installed, which OpenCV uses internally to encode/decode images.

Answer (score 0):

There are a limited number of frames in a video, you are already extracting *all* of them.

`vidcap.read` grabs, decodes and returns the next video frame, and when there are no more frames it will return `false` which is what you are handling already.

---

To rotate try this (change the degree to what you need it to be):

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('20180530_115209.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
h, w = image.shape[:2]
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((w / 2, h / 2), 90, 1.0)
count = 0
success = True
while success:
    rotated90 = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (h, w))
    cv2.imwrite("sushant_2/image/frame%d.jpg" % count, rotated90)     # save frame as JPEG file      
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    print('Read a new frame: ', count)
    count += 1
```

Comment: yeah it worked for me,The image is getting tilted but some part of image is lost( it  is getting cropped from bottom and right borders)